# Error when trying to install a package: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install the [d3 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3) for node with npm or yarn, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
3826 error code EAI_AGAIN
3827 error errno EAI_AGAIN
3828 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/d3-quadtree/-/d3-quadtree-1.0.3.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
```

I have no problem installing other packages. Also when I visit the d/l link the package is being manually downloaded.

Is this a sudo thing?

I'm using nvm on my local machine if it helps.